# How to sync two CalDAV servers

Tags: synchronization, owncloud, horde, caldav

My work calendar is stored on my employer's Horde server.  I also have my own owncloud instance running.

What I would like to do is store also my work calendar on my owncloud instance, and have a script which mirrors this calendar to my Horde account.  I know that only I make changes to the calendar on the Horde server, so a one-directional sync from owncloud to Horde would be just fine.

Both owncloud and Horde support CalDAV; Horde in adition has some XMLRPC service.  I have root access to the owncloud instance, but for the Horde server, I only have Horde's web login. I'd be grateful for any suggestions on how to do this synchronisation.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any solution yet.

Answer (score 6):

vdirsyncer https://github.com/untitaker/vdirsyncer
by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1544347/markus-unterwaditzer
can do this via CardDAV, two-way as well.

I'd advise doing it via multiple runs against a local "vdir" rather than directly, and you can even implement git VCS for data security.

Answer (score 0):

https://syncevolution.org/ should be able to do this, but don't expect it to be stable. This seems to be still somewhat experimental technology.